# Problema ao salvar informações do DropDownList no banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms

estou com problema em salvar informações no dropDown pelo o btn-salvar 
tenho um formulário de cadastro de imoveis sendo que as informações inseridas no dropdown ocorre so que na hora que eu salvo em uma outra pagina (que seria essa) nao consigo salvar no banco de dados, o que poderia ser? 
 segue o codigo 
ASPX.CS

```
     protected void btnSalvarImovel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        try
        {
            Imovel a = new Imovel();
            Convert.ToInt32(ddlCidade.SelectedItem.Value);
            Convert.ToInt32(ddlLocalizacao.SelectedItem.Value);
            Convert.ToInt32(ddlOperacao.SelectedItem.Value);
            Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoImovel.SelectedItem.Value);
            a.Titulo = txtTitulo.Text;
            a.QntQuarto = Convert.ToInt32(txtQtdQuartos.Text);
            a.Obs = txtObservacao.Text;
            a.Valor = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text);

            ImovelDao d = new ImovelDao();
            d.SalvarImovel(a);
            txtObservacao.Text = string.Empty;
            txtQtdQuartos.Text = string.Empty;
            txtTitulo.Text = string.Empty;
            txtValor.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

DAL

```
       public void SalvarImovel(Imovel i)
    {
        try
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Imovel(IdCidade,IdLocal,Idtipo,IdOperacao,Titulo,Obs,QntQuarto,Valor) VALUES(@IdCidade,@IdLocal,@Idtipo,@IdOperacao,@Titulo,@Obs,@QntQuarto,@Valor)", Conexao.connection);
            Conexao.connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCidade", i.IdCidade);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdLocal", i.IdLocal);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTipo", i.IdTipo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdOperacao", i.IdOperacao);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", i.Titulo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Obs", i.Obs);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QntQuarto", i.QntQuarto);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor", i.Valor);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Erro ao salvar o Imóvel, atualize a página e tente novamente, se persistir o erro, contate o suporte" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Conexao.connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Que erro você esta tendo? Teria como colocar o código do seu `SalvarImovel`

Comment: @PabloVargas Editei a pergunta ali em cima, queria que quando cadastrar no dropdown ele salve no IdCidade o que devo fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa fazer é atribuir os valores dos seus `DropDownList` para suas respectivas propriedades

```
            Imovel a = new Imovel();
            a.IdCidade = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCidade.SelectedItem.Value);
            a.IdLocal = Convert.ToInt32(ddlLocalizacao.SelectedItem.Value);
            a.IdOperacao = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOperacao.SelectedItem.Value);
            a.IdTipo = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTipoImovel.SelectedItem.Value);
            a.Titulo = txtTitulo.Text;
            a.QntQuarto = Convert.ToInt32(txtQtdQuartos.Text);
            a.Obs = txtObservacao.Text;
            a.Valor = Convert.ToDouble(txtValor.Text);

            ImovelDao d = new ImovelDao();
            d.SalvarImovel(a);
            txtObservacao.Text = string.Empty;
            txtQtdQuartos.Text = string.Empty;
            txtTitulo.Text = string.Empty;
            txtValor.Text = string.Empty;
```

Só realizar a conversão para Int32 não é o suficiente.

Comment: muito obrigado!!! funcionou